# Iterate over static properties of a class

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

To access a static method, we use

```
[namespace.ClassName]::MethodName()
```

and for static properties we use

```
[namespace.ClassName]::Property
```

How do I iterate through all the static properties inside this class?

```
$list = [namespace.ClassName] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property
```

Returns me a list of all the static properties, but how do I use it, i.e access its value.
If I want to pass the variable to a method, how do I do so? `$list[0]` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work with a `foreach` loop over the `Name` property.

```
$class = [namespace.ClassName] 
$list = $class | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property
$list | select -expand Name | foreach {
   "$_ = $($class::$_)"
}
```

Note that you can iterate over classes if needed by changing the `$class` variable.

Using the `[Math]` class for an example:

```
PS> $class = [math]
PS> $class | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | select -expand Name | foreach { "$_ = $($class::$_)" }
E = 2.71828182845905
PI = 3.14159265358979
```

Comment: Thanks @RyanBernrose

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same as the answer by Ryan Bemrose, but written as a function that spits out objects.

```
function Get-StaticProperties
{
    Param (
        [type]$Class
    )

    gm -InputObject $Class -Static -MemberType Property |
        select -ExpandProperty Name | foreach {
            New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{ Name=$_; Value=$Class::$_ })
        }
}
```

Then, to invoke it:

```
PS> Get-StaticProperties System.Math

Name            Value
----            -----
E    2.71828182845905
PI   3.14159265358979
```